# Understanding a Matrix: What does it represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

What I mean is that sometimes matrices represent linear equations, and other times vertices of polygons, etc. This gets very confusing. How would I know if someone doesn't explicitly state it, what is being represented?

Comment: A matrix doesn't have multiple representations but multiple interpretations. Anyone can interprate it as he wants.

Comment: You wouldn't know. Matrices are a way of coding some mathematical structure. If someone doesn't tell you what is being coded, how would you know?

Comment: The same reason you cannot tell the difference between 2 representing 2 apples or 2 oranges.

Answer (score 3):

A matrix is simply an array.

You will know a matrix when you see one as they look like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \\ i & j & k & l\\ m & n & o & p \end{bmatrix}$$

As for what it *represents*; that will be given in the context of the mathematics.

But here are some general things to look out for:

For example, if you are just given on it's own:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      3&1&2&3\\
      7&4&5&6\\
      1&8&4&2
    \end{array}
\right]$$

then this is known as the Augmented matrix and usually means

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      3&1&2&3\\
      7&4&5&6\\
      1&8&4&2
    \end{array}
\right]=\begin{cases}
3x+y+2z=3 \\ 
7x+4y+5z=6 \\ 
x+8y+4z=2
\end{cases}$$

Also note that if you see a matrix ${A}$ written as $$\det{A}=\begin{vmatrix}a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \\ i & j & k & l\\ m & n & o & p \end{vmatrix}$$ Then you are dealing with the determinant of matrix ${A}$.

Also, if you see
$$
{B}=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{pmatrix}
$$
this can be represented as three column-vectors
$$
\vec v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\\7\end{pmatrix},\vec v_2=\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\\8\end{pmatrix}\text{ and } \vec v_3=\begin{pmatrix}3\\6\\9\end{pmatrix},
$$

Comment: I think it is quite important to note that matrices can be seen, in some part of mathematics, as $n\times m$ vectors on a field $\mathbb{F}$. They are represented as arrays because we can define product, useful structures,... or find interesting properties,... in an easier way than if we wrote them as usual vectors.

Comment: I have to quibble with the “normally” in your opening paragraph. I don’t think that I’ve ever seen names of matrices underlined in typeset mathematical text, nor in blackboard scribbles, for that matter.

Comment: @amd That's a good point actually, I've just checked and it seems underlining them is non-standard (even though it was what I was taught when I was younger). In textbooks these days they seem to be in boldface. In any case I have adjusted my answer in accordance with your comment, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

At the bare-bones-level an $(m\times n)$-matrix $A$ with real entries is a function
$$A:\quad [m]\times[n]\to{\mathbb R},\qquad (i,k)\mapsto a_{ik}\ .$$
This means that $A$ is in the first place a **data structure**: a family of $m\cdot n$ real numbers organized and addressed in a particular way.

It just so happens that such structures turn up every day as well in real life (spread-sheets) as in the most diverse areas of mathematics. It is generally agreed that the "visual expression" of $A$ is a rectangular array of the numbers $a_{ik}$, whereby the the numbers $a_{i1}$, $a_{i2}$, $\ldots$, $a_{in}$ constitute the $i^{\rm th}$ horizontal row of this array.

For special purposes, e.g., in linear algebra, special conventions are in force. For example, if the matrices $A$ and $B$ are both of the same "bi-size" $(m\times n)$ their sum $A+B$ is defined, and under other favorable circumstances the product $A\cdot B$ is defined. These definitions were not arbitrarily chosen by the mathematical community (note that $A+B$ is "element-wise", but $A\cdot B$ is not), but have a a well understandable interpretation in the environment were these matrices $A$ and $B$ are coming to existence.

Maybe you knew all this; but there is not more to it.